# Retrieved anchors list gets corrupted?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to analyze anchor links ( their `text` property ) in PhantomJS.

The retrieval happens here:

```
var list = page.evaluate(function() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('a');
});
```

this will return an object with a property `length` which is good (the same `length` I get when running `document.getElementsByTagName('a');` in the console). But the vast majority of the elements in the object have the value of `null` which is not good.. I have no idea why this is happening.

I have been playing with converting to a real array thru `slice` which did no good. I have tried different sites, no difference. I have dumped the .png file to verify proper loading and the site is properly loaded.

This is obviously not the full script, but a minimal script that shows the problem on a well known public site ;)

How can I retrieve the full list of anchors from the loaded page ?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onError = function(msg, trace) 
{ //Error handling mantra
  var msgStack = ['PAGE ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) 
{ //Error handling mantra
  var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
  phantom.exit(1);
};

function start( url )
{
  page.open( url , function (status)
  {
    console.log( 'Loaded' ,  url , ': ' , status  );
    if( status != 'success' )
      phantom.exit( 0 );

    page.render( 'login.png');

    var list = page.evaluate(function() {
      return  document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    });

    console.log( 'List length: ' , list.length );

    for(  var i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++ )
    {
     if( !list[i] )
      {
        console.log( i , typeof list[i] ,  list[i] === null , list[i] === undefined );
        //list[i] === null -> true for the problematic anchors
        continue;
      }
      console.log( i,  list[i].innerText , ',' , list[i].text /*, JSON.stringify( list[i] ) */ );
    }
    //Exit with grace
    phantom.exit( 0 );
  });
}    

start( 'http://data.stackexchange.com/' );
//start( 'http://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/' );
```

Comment: `typeof list[i] === null` is true

Comment: I don't know phantom that well and I can't test it right now myself, but could you check what happens if you move your `for` loop inside of the callback of the `page.evaluate` (`function() {var list = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); ... your for loop ...}`)

Comment: As [phantomjs.org:evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) has the note: `the arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.` I guess, that Nodes or Lists become invalid after the callback is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of phantomjs permits only primitive types (boolean, string, number, `[]` and `{}`) to pass to and from the page context. So essentially all functions will be stripped and that is what DOM elements are. [t.niese found the quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700432/retrieved-anchors-list-gets-corrupted#comment38304758_24700432) from the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**

You need to do a part of the work inside of the page context. If you want the `innerText` property of every node, then you need to map it to a primitive type first:

```
var list = page.evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(a){
        return a.innerText;
    });
});
console.log(list[0]); // innerText
```

You can of course map multiple properties at the same time:

```
return Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(a){
    return { text: a.innerText, href: a.href };
});
```