# Collecting all links on a webpage with phantomjs-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, screen-scraping

Where I am (adapted from first answer at [how to scrape links with phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944518/how-to-scrape-links-with-phantomjs)):

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
ph.createPage(function (page) {
  page.open('http://www.' + currentSite + '.com', function (status) {
    if(status == 'success'){

      page.evaluate(function() { return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a')); }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
....
```

But unfortunately the result is always coming up as null. Returning the whole document (or directly returning a querySelector on the document) causes my computer to hang up.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieved anchors list gets corrupted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700432/retrieved-anchors-list-gets-corrupted)

Comment: Have you tried using Phantomjs' page.content property? You might be able to get all the hrefs in the page this way. Else, try returning document.body.innerHTML instead of [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), then locate the hrefs in this.